# Google App Engine and database "Views"

Tags: google-app-engine, view, google-cloud-datastore, bigtable, denormalization

I'm developing an application for GAE that has a fairly complex data model.

Based on my understanding, a good way to handle a complex data model using a noSQL database, especially GAE, is to  use de-normalized "views" of data.  If the browser-client wants to update some data, the server performs a write on some core data, returns "200 OK" so the client can continue, then uses the task que to update any "views" that the written data may have affected.

Then whenever the client wants to query for some objects that would normally require a SQL-join, it can instead query a "view" where all the data it needs is right there in the same "row" (or entity, in app engine's case).

The problem I am having is that all this creating and updating of views seems to be something that a library should be doing, not something I should be doing manually.  Is there a tool that works with GAE where you can specify some views of your data and then expect that they will be created and handled appropriately?  I believe CouchDB does this...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Views are more usually an RDBMS feature than a nonrel one. What you're describing sounds like materialized views, though, and while they're a valid solution, they're not a common one, and thus there aren't any libraries for App Engine (that I'm aware of) that do this.

More common is to simply store your data denormalized in a fashion that facilitates efficient reading, and update the data directly at write time.

Comment: Hey Nick, thanks for your response.  What is the normal thing to do in an instance when some data is updated that is copied(denormalized) in very many other objects.  For example, if an employee's first name is changed and his name is copied into over 1000 appointments that he's been on over the years?

Comment: @DutrowLLC In that specific case, I would argue that they shouldn't be changed, since that was his name at the time of the appointment. In general, don't denormalize like that if you expect the value in question to change. If you have to, then update the source, and use the task queue or a mapreduce type process to update everything.

Comment: I think I see what you are saying.  So for a relationship where one object is copied in more than one other places, you would copy the changes up to a certain number of times at write time; however if the number of copies was above a certain threshhold, you would use the task queue?  But there is no library for this...  Is this not a common scenario with app engine?

Comment: @DutrowLLC No, I would either design it such that the number of places to write is constrained - for example, keeping a count separate from the records being counted only requires one additional update - or I would use a batch update process to do these updates in aggregate. It's rarely the case that you need to denormalize something that's mutable to an unbounded number of duplicates, though.